Как определить id чата телеграмм для Бота?
Скачал готовый код для телеграмм бота с гит хаба.
В коде нужно указать ID чата, в который бот будет присылать информацию
При запуске выскакивает ошибка:

TG_CLIENT_ID = int(os.getenv('-10022295917'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: int() argument must be a
string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Не понимаю в чем ошибка ?
Я пробовал писать неотрицательное значение, но тогда:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
real number, not 'NoneType'

почему то не видит аргумент.

А зачем вам переменные окружения? Укажите просто напрямую TG_CLIENT_ID=-10022295917

Теперь вот такая ошибка вылетает:
await writer.write_headers(status_line, self.headers)
File "C:\Users\Dmitriy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http_writer.py", line 129, in write_headers
buf = _serialize_headers(status_line, headers)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx", line 132, in aiohttp._http_writer._serialize_headers
File "aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx", line 109, in aiohttp._http_writer.to_str
TypeError: Cannot serialize non-str key None

Теперь работает. Но информация в exel документы не записывается

Теперь ещё  и эксель документ появился...  вы мне предлагаете сванговать?) Думаю вы опять не верно задаёте конфигурационные данные для скрипта(или не задаёте их вовсе, на что указывает None), но уже в другом месте.
